# How to find a sum of a sequence if i can't see what kind of a sequence it is?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

In problems where I have to find the limit of a given sequence example
**$\lim_{n→∞}1 \big(\frac{1}{1·2}+\frac{1}{2·3}+ . . .+\frac{1}{n·(n + 1)}\big)$**
                                                                                 how can i find what that sequence equals to in order to solve the limit? 
or example find the limit of
**$\lim_{n→∞}1 \big(\frac{1}{(4·5)} + \frac{1}{(5·6)} + \frac{1}{(6·7)} +...+ \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)}\big) ?$**

Comment: As @Jacky Chong has showed similar lines can be used to prove the second case.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is no general algorithm. But, the example you gave, it is a series of type $$\dfrac{1}{(a+d)(a+2d)}+\dfrac{1}{(a+2d)(a+3d)}...+\dfrac{1}{(a+(n-2)d)(a+(n-1)d)}$$

You can sum this series by making it a telescoping sum, and then compute the limit.